# Define a method for multiple searches by hibernate in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

My application have large search form with to many inputs for each entity attributes , I want to define a method for example criteria method for generic query search , instead of defining method for search by each entity attribute , how can I do this with hibernate or JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

Using JpaSpecificationExecutor ([scroll down to section 5](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries)

This way you can programmatically define what fields are you going to add to your where clause, like this .:

```
(Specification<Book>) (book, cq, cb) ->
  cb.and(
    // You can dynamically construct that array of predicates based on which fields are set in the form
    cb.like(book.get("author"), "%" + author + "%"),
    cb.like(book.get("title"), "%" + title + "%")
  )
```